# Using Spring as a backend for grails front end

Tags: java, spring, grails

We have a Spring application which exposes all the business logic as RESTful web services, which is consumed by the jQuery front end. Our jQuery front end code is becoming unmanageable with javascript manipulating the html files. So we are planning to use grails with jquery/bootstrap to overcome these issues. Right now, we are doing a Poc to understand the implications of moving to new stack.

Our current understanding is that we will run two applications - one for grails and one for Spring backend. We can  implement CAS to maintain the session between these two apps. Grails will use spring for all data as well as business logic. Our front end communicates only with grails, which in turn connects to Spring as need basis.

I am not sure what are the potential things to look for in the new approach. Can someone provide 
feedback on our approach?

Thanks
--Venky

Comment: Don't see any problem, have implemented same approach few times

Comment: You can easily implement a GORM plugin, which uses a REST service to fill the domain objects with data and you can use Grails as usual. There are laready some attempts to this approach, but nothing generic I know about. I believe it is mostly very domain specific, so there is not much sence to make the result public.

Comment: I agree with @TomMetz we are using the same patterns in production. Grails web app that communicates to Camel Rest App, and other Grails rest apps.

Comment: ... based on this: " Our jQuery front end code is becoming unmanageable with javascript manipulating the html files.", I'm just curious what exactly are you trying to solve? How would grails help here? Not 'smarting' here, just wondering what I'm missing. My first impression is that whatever unwieldy monster you have now will get shoved into deeper woods.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create only one app, in grails. Plug all your existing code into src/java and use groovy domains/services to get data from you existing business logic.

In this way you will not have the overhead to run 2 webapps that will communicate over http to serve one client request.